# How can I make left/right button disappear when the scroll gets to the end of the container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created a list of tab items, wrapped by a `<ul>` container. I have given this container a `max-width` and `overflow-x` properties, so the list of tab items overflows it.

This is the base code for the `<ul>` wrapper and the mapped list of tab items.

```
      <ul className="tabs" ref={wrapperRef}>
        {tabs.map((tab) => (
          <li
            onClick={() => setActive(tab)}
            className={`tab ${tab === active ? "active" : ""}`}
            key={tab}
          >
            {tab}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

Then, I have added two buttons, positioned absolute, to the left and the right. These buttons will scroll to the left end or the right end of the container. When we get to the right end of the container, for example, the "Right" button must disappear. Same for the other side, the "Left" button disappears.

The code is as follows:

```
    <div className="tabs__wrapper">
      <ul className="tabs" ref={wrapperRef}>
        {tabs.map((tab) => (
          <li
            onClick={() => setActive(tab)}
            className={`tab ${tab === active ? "active" : ""}`}
            key={tab}
          >
            {tab}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
        <button className="left" onClick={() => adjustView("left")}>
          Left
        </button>
        <button className="right" onClick={() => adjustView("right")}>
          Right
        </button>
      }
    </div>
```

However, there is a problem. If we interact with the scroll manually, the buttons are still displayed like the last time we've interacted with them. For example, if I click the "Right" button, it scrolls to the end and the "Right" button disappears as expected, but, if I use the mouse to scroll the container to the left side, the "Right" button is still hidden, when it should show up, and the "Left" button should be hidden instead.

How can I do this?

Oh and one more thing, I would like the buttons to disappear only when the scroll has finished. I guess conditionally rendering the Buttons is not a solution anymore.

Here is the full Sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/tab-scroll-3tzi80

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this (see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tab-scroll-forked-0zzpob?file=/src/App.js:419-624) ):

Listen for scroll event:

```js
      <ul className="tabs" ref={wrapperRef} onScroll={handleScroll}>
```

calculate if we're left, right or in between with the scroll event params, and update state:

```js
  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (wrapperRef.current) {
      const { scrollLeft, scrollWidth, clientWidth } = wrapperRef.current;
      switch (scrollLeft + clientWidth) {
        //Scroll is utter left
        case clientWidth:
          setDisableButton("left");
          break;
        //Scroll is utter right
        case scrollWidth:
          setDisableButton("right");
          break;
        //Scroll somewhere in between
        default:
          setDisableButton("none");
      }
    }
  };
  
  //Adjust view based on state
  function adjustView(position) {
    if (position === "left") {
      scrollTabbar(wrapperRef?.current, 0);
    } else {
      scrollTabbar(wrapperRef?.current, wrapperRef.current?.scrollWidth);
    }
  }
```

The buttons also disappear only when scrolling is finished, so that's solved too! Both buttons are shown when we're neither left nor right.

Comment: This is nice, but I found some cases where the scrollLeft + clientWidth is 1px less than scrollWidth, which makes the right button not to hide. Why is this happening?

Comment: Btw, is there a library that can make my life easier, rather than just doing this functionality myself?

Comment: Do you have an example of when this happens? I could take a look.

Comment: Right when I open the codepen posted above. Maybe it’s on some specific resolutions, don’t know.